# Unable to resolve the import in Eclipse while connecting to server

Tags: java, android

Following is the code snippet I'm using for sending an image to server in Eclipse. For the two imports shown below, I'm unable to find the correct jar files to be imported into the project.

```
import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;
```

These two imports are used to facilitate for the following method

```
        private void uploadImage(String p) {
            String path = p;
            String name = "college";
            try{
                String uploadid= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                new MultipartUploadRequest(this,uploadid,UPLOAD_URL)
                        .addFileToUpload(path,"image")
                        .addParameter("name",name)
                        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }
```

After searching in the internet I couldn't find the exact libraries to be included in the project. Is it because I'm using Eclipse ADT instead of Android Studio.?

Comment: so you have found the gradle equivalent?

Comment: Looks like you should import this lib: https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service. Read their wiki to get started